# get values from same textfield in custom cell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uitextfield

I have one custom cell in a table with one textfield (cell.guestName.text), users add more rows depending on how many guests they have. I am struggling with fetching the guest name entered in each guest field.

Can anyone help me do this please?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use an `NSMutableArray` to keep track of the Guest Names for each row in the `TableView`.  Then it is just a matter of adding to that array each time a new row is added to the TV.  Getting the value of all cells or just one cell is easy to with `objectAtIndex` or a for-in loop on the `Array`

Comment: when I try this I get the following in the log

(
    "<NSIndexPath 0xa2bfc40> 2 indexes [0, 0]",
    "<NSIndexPath 0xa2bd780> 2 indexes [0, 1]"
)

Comment: Use the `indexPath.row` property for the index in your `NSArray`

Answer (score 0):

You get the number of rows and sections (but probably you already know that number) with `numberOfSections` and `numberOfRowsInSection`.
Then you get all cells using `cellForRowAtIndexPath` passing all the possibile index paths, and you retrieve the text.

**Example:**

```
for(NSUInteger i=0; i< [self.tableView numberOfSections]; i++)
{
    for(NSUInteger j=0; j<[self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection: i]; j++)
    {
        NSIndexPath* path= [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem: j inSection: i];
        UITableViewCell* cell= [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: path];
        // Do whatever with the cell
    }
}
```